# Trying to set a subset of a vector to equal another vector, but everything gets set to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to get into Python for statistics, coming from an R background. I've set up a script for cross validation on a dataset I've been working with:

```
cvIndex = np.remainder(np.arange(dat.shape[0]), 10)
pred = np.arange(dat.shape[0])

for i in range(10):
    #get training and test set
    trFeatures = dat[cvIndex != i, :]
    teFeatures = dat[cvIndex == i, :]
    trY = y[cvIndex != i]

    #fit random forest
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, random_state = 42)
    rf.fit(trFeatures, trY);

    #make and store prediction
    tePred = rf.predict_proba(teFeatures)[:, 1]
    pred[cvIndex == i] = tePred.copy()

print(pred)
```

which returns a vector of all zeros. As far as I can tell, this is the proper way to set a subset of a vector to equal another vector (and indeed, I've tried doing this with some dummy vectors, with success). The other obvious potential problem is that the tePred could be all zeros, but extracting any specific case (i=9) for example, gives this:

```
i = 9
#get training and test set
trFeatures = dat[cvIndex != i, :]
teFeatures = dat[cvIndex == i, :]
trY = y[cvIndex != i]

#fit random forest
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, random_state = 42)
rf.fit(trFeatures, trY);

#make and store prediction
tePred = rf.predict_proba(teFeatures)[:, 1]

print(tePred[1:50])

[ 0.264  0.034  0.02   0.002  0.     0.014  0.     0.     0.     0.102
  0.14   0.     0.024  0.002  0.     0.002  0.004  0.     0.044  0.     0.382
  0.042  0.     0.004  0.     0.112  0.002  0.074  0.     0.016  0.012
  0.004  0.     0.     0.006  0.002  0.01   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.004
  0.002  0.002  0.044  0.004  0.     0.     0.004]
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like integer coercion to me. `np.arange` returns an integer array which you then update in-place. As an in-place operation cannot change an array's dtype the r.h.s. will be converted to int. With your input being probabilities this will be all zeros.

Since you are overwriting all of `pred` eventually you needn't initialize it to anything, so using `np.empty(dat.shape[0])` which defaults to a float dtype instead of `np.arange` should fix your code.

Two unrelated side notes:

- taking a copy of tePred on the last line of the loop is not necessary.
- Python like C uses zero-based indexing, so `tePred[1:50]` skips the first element.